# Integer solutions to the non linear Diophantine equation $x^5+y^5=47$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I need to determine weather the equation $x^5+y^5=47$ has integer solutions.
The way i was taught to do this was to take modulo 4 of the entire equation and check if the sides are equal, so taking modulo 4 of the equation I get:
$$[x^5]_4+[y^5]_4=[47]_4$$
So the possible values of both $[x^5]$ & $[y^5]$ are $\{0,1,3\}$ and $[47]_4=3$ so there has to be some values of x and y that satisfy that equation right?

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: $x^5+y^5$ factors.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just picking an arbitrary modulus like $4$ is unlikely to work very well. You want to pick a modulus that will work well with the powers you have.

In this case, a good one to try is $11$, because there are only three possibilities for $x^5 \bmod {11}$: $-1$, $0$, and $1$. (Granted, there are only three possibilities modulo $4$, too, but that's $\frac34$ of all possibilities, whereas here we get only $\frac{3}{11}$ of all possibilities.) In general, we want to pick a modulus $m$ such that $\phi(m)$ is a small multiple of $5$, and it only makes sense to consider primes and powers of primes.

So the possible values of $x^5 + y^5 \bmod{11}$ are $-2,-1,0,1,2$, but $47 \equiv 3 \pmod {11}$, which is not one of the possible values.

Comment: hi sorry to bother you but what does phi(m) mean?

Comment: @Questlove The number of $k$ with $1\le k\le m$ and $\gcd(k,m)=1$

Comment: $\phi(m)$ is Euler's [totient function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Totient_function). It's present here because of [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), a generalization of [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem): for any $m$, if $\gcd(a,m) = 1$, then $a^{\phi(m)} \equiv 1 \pmod m$.  Here, Fermat's theorem is actually all we need: for all $a$ not divisible by $11$, $a^{10} \equiv 1 \pmod{11}$, which means there are few possibilities for $a^5$ as well.

Answer (score 6):

There are no solutions.  It's easy to see there are no solutions with x and y positive.  If one of them is negative, x+y is a proper divisor and 47 is prime, so x and y must differ by 1 in absolute value.  This is now also easy to eliminate since adjacent 5th powers never differ by 47.

Also, solvability mod some number is not a sufficient condition for solvability in integers (except in special cases).  It is only a necessary condition.  So you can only use it to prove a solution in integers does not exist.  You can't generally use it to prove a solution exists...you have to do more work for that.

Comment: You might want to state explicitly that tour factor argument is based on the fact that $x^5+y^5=(x+y)(x^4-x^3y+x^2y^2-xy^3+y^4)$

Comment: It could have been, but it wasn't.   It was based on x-y divides x^n - y^n for all positive n, since I had already eliminated the case that both terms were positive.  :)